# Which Unreal Engine 4 version runs best on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics

Intel® Core™ i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] / GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
15,5 GiB
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

I would like to install UE4 4.25 on my PC. I have followed all the steps correctly from https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/index.html. The installation itself was really slow and the application stucks while loading the program. Is there any version of this application that runs stable on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers? Which version? And was the installation itself really slow, the git cloning or both?

Comment: As i know i have the latest (460.56) Nvidia driver installed. Both process were extremely long it took over 1 and half hour.

Comment: It is a lot to install so not surprising. I assume you have Secure Boot disabled because otherwise even if correctly installed the proprietary drivers aren't in use.

Comment: So I should change it in UEFI setup then?

Comment: and u were right it was disabled according to sudo mokutil --sb-state

Comment: No computer from 2012 on, at least, has BIOS. It's all UEFI now and yes, 1) OSes should be installed in UEFI mode and 2) for Linux distros and Nvidia cards it's always recommended to disable Secure boot (in UEFI) whenever using the proprietary drivers.

Comment: i have checked my UEFI settings and secure boot is enabled. (although sudo mokutil --sb-state showed disabled) And for some reason it does not allow to change it.

Comment: Mokutil allows trust on unsigned drivers. If you already followed the wizard in order to trust the Nvidia drivers the effect is the same and can keep Secure Boot enabled in the firmware. But because there's no tangible benefit (of Secure Boot) it's generally recommended to just disable it, it's faster and works across the board. With the mokutil tool users need to repeat the process in any future similar situation.